# Manipulando botões em react.js

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, react-hooks

estou criando um pequeno sistema de tarefas para um colaborador na empresa onde trabalho,  o mesmo deve exibir as tarefas que devem ser concluidas no dia, ate ai eu consegui exibir as tarefas o meu problema aparece quando o colaborador for iniciar a tarefa e finalizar a tarefa, gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de alterar somente o botão especifico da tarefa, as tarefas são exibidas apartir de um map, não sei se seria por isso. Segue o codigo:

```
const ServicosGerais: React.FC = () => {
    const [started, setStarted] = useState('Iniciar Tarefa')
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState<TaskData[]>([]);
    const { signOut, user } = useAuth();

    useEffect(() => {
        api.get('/sistemas/tarefas').then((response) => {
            setTasks(response.data);

        });
    }, []);
  

    const startedtask = useCallback(() => {

        setStarted('Tarefa inciada');
    }, []);

    const finishtask = useCallback(() => {

        console.log('task finish!')

    }, []);


    return (
        <>
            <GlobalContainer>
                <Header />
                <Container>
                    <Headermini>
                        <h1>Olá {user.FIRSTNAME} essas são suas tarefas para hoje: <Moment format={"D MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss"} interval={1000}></Moment>  </h1>
                        <img src={"data:image/jpeg;base64, " + user.AVATAR} alt="" />
                    </Headermini>
                    <ContainerTarefa>
                        {tasks.map(task => (
                            <div className="tarefa" key={task.CODIGO_TAREFA}>
                                <p>{task.DEPARTAMENTO + ' - ' + task.DATA + '-' + task.NOME_DO_DIA}</p>
                                <p>{task.DESCRI_TAREFA}</p>
                                <div className="botoes">
                                    <ButtonStarted
                                        onClick={startedtask}>
                                        {started}</ButtonStarted>
                                    <ButtonFinish onClick={finishtask}>Finalizar Tarefa</ButtonFinish>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </ContainerTarefa>
                </Container>
                <Footer>
                    <nav className="navFooter">
                        <Link className="links" to="/menu"><BsHouseDoorFill size={25} />Menu</Link>
                        <Link className="links" to="/aplicacoes"><BsChevronDoubleLeft size={25} />Voltar</Link>
                        <Link className="links" to="/perfil"><BsFillPersonFill size={25} />Perfil</Link>
                        <button className="button" onClick={signOut}><BsBoxArrowLeft size={25} /> Sair </button>
                    </nav>
                </Footer>
            </GlobalContainer>
        </>
    );
}

export default ServicosGerais;
```

Então o que acontece e o seguinte a lista de tarefa e exibida, como na imagem abaixo
[image: Imagem de uma tarefa do sistema]

o trecho de codigo que realiza essa implementação seria esse abaixo

```
 <ContainerTarefa>
                        {tasks.map(task => (
                            <div className="tarefa" key={task.CODIGO_TAREFA}>
                                <p>{task.DEPARTAMENTO + ' - ' + task.DATA + '-' + task.NOME_DO_DIA}</p>
                                <p>{task.DESCRI_TAREFA}</p>
                                <div className="botoes">
                                    <ButtonStarted
                                        onClick={startedtask}>
                                        {started}</ButtonStarted>
                                    <ButtonFinish onClick={finishtask}>Finalizar Tarefa</ButtonFinish>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </ContainerTarefa>
```

Gostaria que o comportamento dos botões fosse individual, porque quando clico no botão para ele iniciar tarefa todos são mudados ao mesmo tempo! No caso seu for exibida 6 tarefas no dia cada tarefa devera ser tratada idividualmente!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito,mas no teu caso, eu trataria cada elemento HTML individualmente. Colocaria um parâmetro na função finish task, e passaria o elemento html para cada chamada da função:

```
<ButtonStarted onClick={startedtask(task)}> {started} </ButtonStarted>
<ButtonFinish onClick={finishtask(task)}>Finalizar Tarefa</ButtonFinish>
```

Assim tu vai ter só a task atual dentro da função, aí pode manipular ela do jeito que quiser, criar arrays e dar um push nas concluídas, enfim, qualquer coisa.

Uma solução que eu vejo aí, assumindo que você tem um array com as tarefas, e que elas tenham um ID, é a seguinte, passando o parâmetro como eu coloquei ali em cima, mudar tuas funções started e finished pra algo do tipo:

```
startedTask(task) {
    let tasks = this.state.Tasks;
    let x = 0;
    tasks.map(t => {
        if(task.id == t.id)
             // Fazer o que quiser com a tarefa **t** em questão
        x++;
    })
    this.setState({Tasks: tasks});

}
```

Se for alterar o state dentro do if, é só usar usar setState que recebe a variável **tasks** no final das funções finished and started

Do jeito que interpretei o problema, consegui pensar nessa solução, se não te ajudar me responde explicando um pouco melhor.

Comment: Fala @placementw, cara sua logica foi muito boa vou tentar usar aqui, se der certo volto para lhe dar um retorno! Muito obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: @ViniciusLima tranquilo, qualquer dúvida ou erro manda um reply aqui que eu tento entender!

Comment: @ViniciusLima pode ser que tu tenha que usar um bind na hora que chama a função também se daquele jeito não funcionar